# Statements execute but do not append text to the TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a C# WPF app. It takes an URL input from a text box and shows the downloaded html in another text box on a button click. To tell the user wait till the webpage is downloaded, I am appending text in the very beginning.

```
public void urlAnalyzer()
{
    // Append text to Result box
    Result.AppendText("Please wait, inspecting the URL.\n");

    // Initiating WebClient to download webpage
    WebClient inspecter = new WebClient();

    // try-catch to avoid exception in a generic way
    try
    {
        // stroring downloaded page in savedData
        savedData = inspecter.DownloadString(webpage);

        // appending downloaded html in Result box
        Result.AppendText(savedData);
    }
    catch
    {
        Result.AppendText("You did not enter any valid URL.");
    }
}
```

When the `urlAnalyzer()` is called, `Result.AppendText()` goes to Result text box's event handler method,

```
private void Result_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

This event method is visited every time `Result.AppendText()` is called, but it doesn't append the string to Result box. When the `urlAnalyzer()` function is fully visited, texts then appear in the Result box.

**How to make the appended text appear in the text box when the append statement is executed?** How to update the text box on every text append call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient.DownloadString()` is executed in UI thread and blocks UI updates. Use async version of download method:

```
public async void urlAnalyzer()
{
    // Append text to Result box
    Result.AppendText("Please wait, inspecting the URL.\n");

    // Initiating WebClient to download webpage
    WebClient inspecter = new WebClient();

    // try-catch to avoid exception in a generic way
    try
    {
        // stroring downloaded page in savedData
        savedData = await inspecter.DownloadStringTaskAsync(webpage);

        // appending downloaded html in Result box
        Result.AppendText(savedData);
    }
    catch
    {
        Result.AppendText("You did not enter any valid URL.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Can you please tell me, is there any other way of achieving this without using asynchronous method?

Comment: if you have a long-running operation (like downloading web resource), don't perform it in the UI thread, which is responsible for rendering of interface: it will become unresponsive, being busy with other operation. Such long-running operations should be performed separately (aka in a different `Task`, or via Async functions in .net framework, like DownloadStringTaskAsync). async/await combo is just a nice language feature to synchronize main thread and completed tasks. I don't think there are other ways without any asynchronous method

Comment: So that's why interface was freezing while webpage had been downloading.